# AllowCustomText property is not working in RadComboBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

I have a implemented the Filter in **RadCombobox**, But i does not want user to insert the custom text in the Dropdown so i have set the following property **`AllowCustomText = "False"`** but it is not working and user is able to insert custom text.

**Sample Combobox Code:**

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server"
    AllowCustomText="False" Filter="StartsWith"
    OnClientTextChange="rcbName_ClientTextChange"
    OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="rcbName_ClientSelectedIndexChanged">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Test"/>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Tests"/>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="testData"/>
        <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Other"/>
    </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want this kind of behaviour you need to set MarkFirstMatch = "true" and 
AllowCustomText = "false" that will change user input to the last item that was selected.

Online demo:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/autocompleteclientside/defaultcs.aspx

Kind regards,
Rafal

Comment: I know about that but i want the same fuctionality as Filter but also ristrict the user to does not enter any word which is not present in combobox